# Cannot save customer configuration after making changes instead throws warning

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, openmage

I have only one website and while trying to change customer configuration in system>configuration>customers>customer configuration i get the error "Cannot share customer accounts globally because some customer accounts with the same emails exist on multiple websites and cannot be merged."

[image]

I'm not sure why i'm getting this error as i only run single website.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this issue was due to 2 different accounts with same email being created inside the customer table even though we have only one website.

most likely one of the account with same email has been added due to customer import. deleting one account resolved the problem for me.

The following sql will give the duplicate accounts

```
mysql> SELECT `email`, COUNT(*) FROM magento.customer_entity GROUP BY `email` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Hi, can you pls flag it as resolved? Seems not to be a bug in openmage.